# Plone: get vocabulary in a page template

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying this: `tal:define="terms python:context.portal_vocabularies.getVocabularyByName('a_vocabulary').items()"`

and the result is
`Unauthorized: You are not allowed to access 'portal_vocabularies' in this context`

Any idea how to get my vocabulary in a page template?

(It's working for authenticated users. The error is only for anonymous.)

Comment: You will have better luck getting answers by posting in our forum, community.plone.org, though I posted a link on the forum to your question here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's the easiest... Added a browser view:

```
class AVocabulary(BrowserView):
    def __call__(self):
        terms = self.context.portal_vocabularies.getVocabularyByName(
            'a_vocabulary').items()
        res = [(t[0], t[1].title) for t in terms]
        return res
```

it's public

```
  <browser:page
    name="get_a_vocabulary"
    for="*"
    permission="zope2.View"
    class=".views.AVocabulary"
    />
```

and it's working:

```
tal:define="options python:context.restrictedTraverse('get_a_vocabulary')"
```